# Preloading view in phone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, preloading

When my app launches there's a black screen before the startup view is completely loaded. Is there a way I can have a progressview or something while the app is loading. Just like Mac , windows or any simple app has a preloading screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a preload view you can use **Default.png** image, which will be shown when the app loads.

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) says,

> To enhance the user’s experience at application launch, you must provide at least one launch image. A launch image looks very similar to the first screen your application displays. iOS displays this image instantly when the user starts your application and until the app is fully ready to use. As soon as your app is ready for use, your app displays its first screen, replacing the launch placeholder image.

Answer (score 1):

You can add UIView in `MainWindow.xib` file and see When app Loads, Hide that UIView Programmatically or You can also add animation in UIImageView inside UIView for Progress like Explained below in UIImageView...

```
-(void)setImageAnimation
{
    NSMutableArray *arrImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]);
        [arrImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]]];
    }
    imgViewSending.animationImages = arrImages;
    imgViewSending.animationDuration = 1.0;
    [imgViewSending startAnimating];
    [arrImages release];
}
```

When app loads you can hide that view...

You can also set SplashScreen in your project..Just rename your image as `Default.png`,It will automatically loads that image when app starts..

As I had done this successfully in my application..

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

use splash screen

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/

Comment: Even though many apps use a splash screen, it's not the right thing to do. The Default.png mechanism is there to give the impression that the app is loading quickly. Creating a splash screen as described in your link only adds 2-3 seconds wait each time the app starts up, which slows things down and is nothing but annoying.

Comment: indeed..............but while they want to some animation like fadein fade out then then app will be look nice.am i right?

Comment: The question is about how to avoid a black screen while the first view loads. Default.png is the right answer -- the system will load and display that image very early in the app launch process. Loading an actual view, whether it's the app's main view or a splash image that fades in and out, comes much later. So this "solution" doesn't solve the problem the OP asked about.